# isolating covariates

Tags: r

I am attempting to isolate the following covariates in R: `age`, `educ`, `black`, `hisp`, `married`, `re74`, `re75`, `u74`, and `u75`. I know that I can isolate `age` to `re75` via...

```
(vars = colnames(nsw_psid_withtreated)[2:8])
```

...however, I still need `u74` and `u75` which are columns 10 and 11. What can I do to the following (and above) code to get that?

My data set is `nsw_psid_withtreated`.

```
> colnames(nsw_psid_withtreated)
 [1] "nsw"     "age"     "educ"    "black"   "hisp"   
 [6] "married" "re74"    "re75"    "re78"    "u74"    
[11] "u75"     "u78"    
> (vars = colnames(nsw_psid_withtreated)[2:8])
[1] "age"     "educ"    "black"   "hisp"    "married"
[6] "re74"    "re75"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `c()` function combines things.

```
(vars = colnames(nsw_psid_withtreated)[c(2:8,10:11)])
```

Since you only want to exclude two variables it might be easier to use `c(-1,-9)` ...

Whenever you can it's good practice to refer to columns by name rather than numerical index (because someday the order of your data might change). You can use the `select=` argument of the `subset` command in base R, or the `select()` function in the `dplyr` package, to select columns by name (including with colons to specify ranges and `c()` to combine elements).